# Copying one column to another column in the same table for product listings

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I read some other posts on here but wasnt sure if it completely related to my issue. I need to copy a column called "Title" to another column called "Keywords" within the same table. It is for a classified listing site that has unique sid's, category_sid's and user_sid's, etc..per row.

What would the query be for this? I just want to make sure that nothing else will be affected and that only the Keywords column updates to match the data in the Title column.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of the [`UPDATE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update all rows setting the value of Keywords to the value of Title.

```
update your_table set keywords = title;
```

Comment: hey, what if I have another column that uses the "keywords" column as well...I updated the "keywords" column to match the "title" column but then my "Accessories_title" column went null since i was telling it to use "title".

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say that a "column uses another column". There is afaik no such mechanism in MySQL.